# Whenever I open Hyper on Mac, my screen flashes black for a few seconds

Tags: macos, crash, hyper

I try to use Hyper on my Mac, and it used to work fine. For the last few weeks, my screen would flash black whenever I opened Hyper on my Mac (but not for regular terminal). Is this because I messed up some files? I recently got this Mac so I'm not exactly sure why this has been happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved my settings and reinstalled it. Now it works fine. Must've been a problem since electron was not properly working either.